# How to we get history of sql statements of sysdba?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sysdba

We have been running a list of commands in cli: sqlplus / as sysdba
We did not have "history on" and we logged out of the session. How do we get the list of sql statements we ran before as sysdba?

We tried the following:

```
SELECT
   h.sample_time,
   u.username,
   h.program,
   h.module,
   s.sql_text
FROM
   DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY h,
   DBA_USERS u,
   DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT s
WHERE  sample_time >= SYSDATE - 1
   AND h.user_id=u.user_id
   AND h.sql_id = s.sql_iD
ORDER BY h.sample_time
```

Also tried

```
select * from v$sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Version do you have?
For >= 12 you have to create a Audit policy and assign it to a user.

Example:
CREATE AUDIT POLICY MY_POLICY ACTIONS „Actions“

AUDIT POLICY MY_POLICY by SYS;

[oracle 19 Audit Sys Users](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dbseg/configuring-audit-policies.html#GUID-D352B575-2EA9-451D-9170-FD9298993DEF)

Comment: We have 12.1.0.2.0